# Unable to Editform.aspx in office 365

Tags: sharepoint-designer, office-365, office

I am unable to edit the Newform.aspx or Edit form.aspx page in ofice 365 . Is there any feature where we need to activate it ? I tried in designer but no luck

Comment: Are you enabled New Experience Team Site? if yes so I think you can't customize it

Answer (score 2):

Microsoft disabled all possibilities for HTML, CSS & JavaScript customizations in SPOnline Modern Experiences.

Please let Microsoft know they are making a mistake:

https://sharepoint.uservoice.com/forums/329214-sites-and-collaboration/suggestions/13385364-allow-javascript-customization-and-css-branding-th